# Localy made php to magento directory- magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer

My requirement is sending sms while place order button triggered.

1) Locally I have use one predefined [sms gateway server](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest)

I receive message When I run `http://localhost/send-sms.php`, its not a magento way its fully core php.

2) I have set one event/observer when place order get trigger

I could try with copy the **send-sms.php** content to observer **execute** method, also copy the php library to the same **Observer Class** location but it is not work.

**Observer class execute method**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

require "twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php";
$AccountSid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$AuthToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
$message = $client->account->messages->create(array(
    "From" => "YYYYYYYYY",
    "To" => "YYYYYYYYYY",
    "Body" => "Test message!",
));
echo "Sent message {$message->sid}";
}
```

problem is magento get not recognize **require** URL. (first line of the execute method)

```
 require 'twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php';
 $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
```

Services_Twilio class defined in Twilio.php, localy its work when I move to magento 2. I stuck with this two lines.

Where could I copy the **twilio-php-master** (php libreary)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my mind the right solution should be like this:

1. Add `twilio/sdk` (link on [github](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php) and link on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/twilio/sdk)) at your extension dependencies in the `composer.json`.
2. Create a model where you'll have the opportunity to write a code for sms sending (copy this part of code from the `send-sms.php`).
3. Use this model in your observer in order to send sms.

**PS:** Do not forget to run `setup:upgrade` to load the `twilio/sdk` library

#### UPDATE:

In the Magento root directory you should execute the command (in the terminal):

```
composer require twilio/sdk
```

Then a composer adds the twilio library in the vendor folder and generates the autoloader for it:

[image: twilio in the vendor directory]

After that you can call the `Services_Twilio` class without any `require` (thanks to autoloader) like this:

```
$AccountSid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$AuthToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$client = new \Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
$message = $client->account->messages->create(array(
    "From" => "YYYYYYYYY",
    "To" => "YYYYYYYYYY",
    "Body" => "Test message!",
));
echo "Sent message {$message->sid}";
```

**Note:** do not forget to add "\" before the class name.

Result in debug:

[image: result for twilio in debug]

As you can see, the Twilio class calling (reference) happens without any errors.

In addition, you can add dependence in the `composer.json` file of the module, like this:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/module-module",
    "description": "Sample Module",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": "*",
        "twilio/sdk": "~4.10"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

But it will work only at installation of the module through the composer.

Comment: thanks, I am working on your solution, I will be back to you.

Comment: I try this, please explain bit more. I stuck with require keyword in php. I have updated my question.

Comment: @BilalUsean I've updated my answer

Comment: wow its working @Siarhey. I felt bad, I able to upvote you only one time :-) otherwise destroy upvote :-)